# Windows 10 error - Could not find the recovery environment

Tags: windows-10, windows-error-reporting

I recently bought my Acer Aspire e5-575g-53vg laptop, which came pre-installed with Windows 10. I want to reset it using the recovery partition, which I know it has because I see it in disk management and I have reset this before.

I am getting this error now: "could not find recovery environment". How do I fix it?

Comment: Did you shrink the partition before?

Comment: I did but it worked after i shrank it. I shrank it. Reset windows. And now it wont reset anymore

Comment: I would just do a clean install of Windows 10 (make sure to back up your files). It's more thorough and Windows 10 will automatically activate again anyway. You can also delete the recovery partition and gain some disk space.

Comment: I would like the recovery partition though. Is there anyway to make a new one since nobody knows how to fix it? Id like it on the ssd. Not on a thumb drive or anything

Comment: I figured it out.

Comment: Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer). You might want to convert your comment into an answer ;)

Comment: a simple recovery drive will throw that error, you need to get the complete installation file using Windows 10 Creators here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer to my own question.

**Problem:**

I've reset the PC before but this time I can't. I can see the recovery partition in Windows Disk Manager, but Windows 10 does not use it when trying to reset. The error is "could not find the recovery environment"

**Solution:**

(Note: I came across this command when reading about my problem. I did not find any solutions, but I figured it out by messing around. Its a very simple fix if you have the same circumstances as me. It works for me, although I am unsure why, so I may post why later if I find out).

In the command prompt (run as administrator for this to work), type `reagentc /?`.  It will give you a paragraph of info about the command.

Type `reagentc /enable`.  This will enable Windows RE, which I can only assume stands for something like, say, **W**indows  **R**ecovery  **E**nvironment.

**tada**

Simple.

**Cause:**

I'm not sure yet. I was messing around in the UEFI settings and came across an item that said "Erase all secure boot settings" and "restore secure boot to factory default".  I was also trying to dual-boot Ubuntu with Windows 10. Basically, be careful messing with UEFI or installing Ubuntu because you could do more than stop recovery, you could brick your device and we don't want that.

If I find the cause, I will post it.